# Service start on reboot and stop through Activity

Tags: android

I have next two situation:

- Activity with buttons for starting and stopping service
- If the device gets restarted, I start the same service, using BroadcastReceiver to send Intent on reboot, and then stop it from the Activity like in previous case

In other words, if Service is started in Activity, it should stay active as long as you click on stop button in that Activity (regardless of reboot).

So, I would like to know how to enable stopping service from Activity after reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just call stopService like normal.  Having started at boot time from a BroadcastReceiver doesn't make it special.

Comment: So what happens is that application process is created for BroadcastReceiver, the service being started belongs to it, and so do activities that I start from the launcher, so there is no problem, because they belong to the same process? Is that correct? I'm a bit confused because this looks for me a bit different situation then when you start the app form the launcher.

Comment: @breakpoint : The `Application` is basically a singleton. In other words, when any application component is created, the `Application` itself is created and will remain (at least in skeleton form) until explicitly stopped by the user (using Settings -> Apps for example) or in extreme cases by the system when resources are really low.

Comment: @Squonk thanks and +1. Just one more thing, when stopping application, if you hit the back button in main activity app will be stoped, unless it has a service beside, or it consists just of a service, then it needs to be stopped through settings, if there's not another way of doing it?

Comment: @breakpoint : Using the BACK button simply takes you 'back' - it doesn't truly stop the application. It might simply return you to the previous `Activity` if it wasn't destroyed using `finish()` or it might keep you in the same `Activity` but simply remove a `Fragment` and pop the previous `Fragment` from the back stack. The only ways an app is truly stopped is if it has to 'force close' due to an unhandled exception OR a user uses 'force stop' in Settings OR a device reboot OR an update to the app itself.

Comment: @Squonk Ok, but what happens if you start the main activity from the launcher, and hit the back button? And it doesn't contain any fragments. Is then the application stopped?

Comment: @breakpoint : "Is then the application stopped?" - No. All that happens is your `Activity` is 'finished'. The 'application' itself remains even if your `Service` isn't running. The reason Android retains a bare-bones instance of the `Application` is it makes it quicker and more efficient to start up the next time a user wants to use it.

Comment: @Squonk Hmm, I thought that that way is inefficient, because it takes up more memory that needed, but when you point it in that way, it does make sense. Thanks!